# Need help with correct SQL query

Tags: mysql

So I asked a similar question yesterday, and got a great response - I'm hoping for the same luck this time around.  What I'm trying to create is paged results for a MySQL query.  I'm taking advantage of LIMIT.  Here is my query.

```
SELECT 
  BookingInfo.ClinicID, BookingInfo.BookingDate, BookingInfo.BookingTime, 
  BookingInfo.Status, PatientBooking.FirstName, PatientBooking.LastName, 
  PatientBooking.DateOfBirth 
FROM BookingInfo 
  LEFT JOIN PatientBooking 
    ON BookingInfo.PatientID = PatientBooking.PatientID 
WHERE PatientBooking.FirstName = 'Brian' 
  AND PatientBooking.LastName = 'Lang' 
  AND (BookingInfo.ClinicID = '1' OR BookingInfo.ClinicID = '2') 
LIMIT '0, 20' 
ORDER BY BookingInfo.BookingDate DESC
```

This query does not work (However if I remove the LIMIT '0,20' part it works just fine).  Instead I get this error returned: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''0, 20' ORDER BY BookingInfo.BookingDate DESC' at line 1

Any ideas from the experts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the limit should come after the order. But what about is not working?

Answer (score 4):

Your `LIMIT` clause should not be enclosed in quotes. It should just read `LIMIT 0, 20`. Quotes are usually reserved for character strings.

Also, the `LIMIT` clause must appear after the `ORDER BY` clause. See SheepSimulator's answer for details.

[Ref](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this is a learning experience for me.  Unfortunately I am still getting the same error, even after I adjusted my query.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is ClinicID a number? Or is it really a char?

Answer (score 1):

Your ORDER clause should be placed before the LIMIT clause.

Check out the [MySQL syntax table for SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

Answer (score 1):

1. The LIMIT clause should be after the ORDER BY clause.
2. It's format is `LIMIT 0, 20` not `LIMIT '0, 20'`.

Reference: [MySQL SELECT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).